# Does every analytic function pass through all points in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function $f(z)$ is analytic and defined everywhere, do its values pass through every point in the complex plane?

In other words, is there for any $z$ in the complex plane an $a$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(a)=z$?

Comment: What about $f(z)=0$? It is never equal to $1$. Or, for that matter, it is never equal to $a$, for every $a\ne0$.

Comment: This is (little) Picard's theorem for nonconstant entire functions, namely they take all but at most one value (eg $e^z$ is never zero and $e^z+1$ is never $1$, while $\sin z$ takes all values)

Answer (score 4):

> In other words, is there for any $z$ in the complex plane an $a$ in $\Bbb C$ such that $f(a)=z$?

No.  Two counter-examples:

1. A constant function takes only 1 value.
2. $\exp(z) \neq 0$ for any $z\in \Bbb C$, same for the Gamma function.

There are however results like [Picars's Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) (cited from Wikipedia):

> **Little Picard Theorem:** If a function $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) and non-constant, then the set of values that $f(z)$ assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.

and

> **Great Picard's Theorem:** If an analytic function $f$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at a point $w$, then on any punctured neighborhood of $w$, $f(z)$ takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single exception, infinitely often.

Notice that in the latter case allows $w=\infty$.  For example, $f(z)=\exp(1/z)$ has an essantial singularity at 0, this in any neighborhood of 0, $f$ takes all complex number with at most one exception.  For this $f$, the is actually one exception, namely $f(z) = 0$ is never realized.

The theorem also applies to $f(1/z)$ which has an essential singularity at $\infty$, i.e. in any neighborhood of $\infty$, $e^z$ takes on each complex number as a value infinitely many times, with the one exception that $e^z\neq 0$.

Comment: About Great Picard's Theorem, our professor said us "the function becomes crazy in the vicinity of an essential singularity".